# Uploading profile pic from user side . Any update methods in views.py to do so using HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**models.py**
*I have created a model of ImageField and migrated on my database*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pic',blank = True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import userprofile

admin.site.register(userprofile)
```

**urls.py**
**This is my URL of the app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any methods to upload pic from user?